# Mute console.log depending on build flag

Tags: javascript, cordova

Is there a flag in the Cordova environment that I can rely on to tell if code is running in production? I want to mute console log with the build flag when it is in the production environment only like the following:

```
if (isProduction) {
  console.log = function () {};
}
```

Currently releases are build like this:

> cordova build ios --release

Is is there a flag an environment which I can rely on?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug

Answer (score 1):

If you worry about security - logs don't work in release mode as I know. You can also define a constant by yourself in your code. For example:

```
const DEBUG = 1;
const RELEASE = 2;
const BUILD_TYPE = RELEASE;

if (BUILD_TYPE == RELEASE) {
  console.log = function () {};
}
```

Also I have found a plugin [cordova-plugin-buildinfo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-buildinfo#buildinfobuildtype)

There is a field

```
BuildInfo.buildType
```

But it works only for android and windows...

UPD
Also you probably can use [hooks](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/hooks/) to do what you want in automatically mode.

Comment: Logs does get dumped out unfortunately, you can see it in Xcode, under Windows -> Device and Simulators -> Device, click the triangle at the bottom.

Comment: I don't understand how I can make use of the hook points to tell the difference between production and development at run time. I will try to see if that buildinfo works, there is a boolean `BuildInfo.debug` flag.

Comment: @huggie you can do next: include a script `buildType.js` in your `index.html` and then your hook will change the script depends on build type. Use `before_build` hook's type and in your hook script you have access to  command-line arguments [Node.js script intefrace](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/hooks/#javascript) . You need a field `cmdLine` in context object -> than parse the string for your "release" . Something like that. Good luck!